# "In this paper, we describe the/an environment..." — should I use "the" or "an"?

Tags: articles, definite-articles, indefinite-articles

I am trying to decide which should be more correct grammatically in the abstract of my paper.

> In this paper, we describe an environment. . . .

or

> In this paper, we describe the environment. . . .

Since I am writing about custom made tool/environment, should I use the or an?

By environment I mean custom tool/application to perform common measuring activity (for engineering topics). So, I guess I can not decide if I should use *the* because it is a custom tool, or *an* because it made to perform common measuring tasks.

Comment: Does it have trees in it? _Environment_ anywhere except outside is a metaphor, and it means what you want it to mean. Without the rest of the context, nobody can tell what  you ought to be saying.

Comment: Agreed.  The answer is "it depends", just... not on what I think you think it depends on :-)  We could probably give good guidance with the rest of the sentence.

Comment: Is it *an* environment (of which multiple may exist) in which the apparatus might be utilized, or is it the environment encompassing the apparatus?

Comment: Even without further clarification, realistically, this is almost surely to call for "*an*", because OP is describing a tool which is novel but not, of necessity, unique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my physics writing, I generally used the indefinite article (a/an), as in

> In this paper, we describe **a** system of randomly moving, weakly interacting particles...

Even if what we were talking about was a specific thing, like a method:

> We discuss **a** novel method for solving such problems...

The reasoning, as mentioned by @brasshat, is that by using "the" we would imply some kind of uniqueness to our system or method. In physics, anyway, there are many ways to skin a cat, and it is presumptuous to phrase things in a way that makes it sound as though you've got the only working solution. Even if you indeed have the only working solution, it's still a matter of etiquette to use "a/an".

Comment: sure, it's "an" in the sense the OP asks about.  good one.

Answer (score 0):

I expect either "the" or "an" would be correct grammatically. From a practical standpoint, if you are absolutely certain that you have created the only possible environment, then by all means use "the". If, however, there is a chance that you or someone else might create a different environment, use "an". My own advice would be to use just a bit of humility, and use "an", and let others describe it as "the".